# Typescript node app deployment process with pm2

Tags: node.js, typescript, deployment, server, pm2

Using pm2 I would like to **deploy a node app written in typescript**. 
The repo of this app sitting on git, the remote machine got an ssh connection to git.

What is the standard work flow for deployment in this case ?

on the git repo of course there's only the source (uncompiled) code, 
and ideally only the compiled (no .ts files) will be sitting on the server.

**On what stage the compilation should take place ? and where ?**

If some of you encounter this scenario and got an actual example, a concrete configuration for this, it would be very very helpful

*Note:* 
Using heroku, I just add a `"postinstall": "npm run build"` script in `package.json` and had a Procfile with somting like `web: npm start`, 
for some reason in this case things are more complicated.

additionally the deployment is to Ec2 linux instance, with standard environment (node, git, pm2 global, and all typescript dependencies if needed, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you use a build-server like travis-CI or gitlab-CI that builds, tests and deploys your source.
I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57560850/continuous-deployment-with-node-express-mongo-app-and-typescript) recently and ended up building the following pipeline:

- build-stage:

  - `npm install` to install `node_modules` *
  - compile typescript to `dist` folder
- test-stage:

  - linting (although some recommend this *before* building)
  - other code inspection
  - unit testing
- deploy: (only on master branch)

  - `npm prune --production` to remove dev-dependencies from `node_modules`
  - use `scp` to copy `dist` and `node_modules` to prod server
  - use `ssh` to remove files from earlier deployments and to tell pm2 to reload `server.js`

* note that if you use modules that use native code and thus are compiled on `npm_install` (node-gyp), you have to make sure your build-server uses the same architecture as your production environment