# continuous deployment with node/express/mongo app and typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, continuous-deployment

From what I have seen so far, nodejs apps get deployed either by creating a completely static bundle (e.g. angular), or by pulling the source from the repo and running `npm install` and `npm start` (usually seen when express/mongo are used).

However, I am developing an express/mongo app paired with typescript, and pulling from the repo would require to build the typescript (again) on the production server, which is ugly and also requires to have typescript and all `@types/*` packages as production-dependencies. So I was wondering: **what are the best practices**? Is it a good idea to build & bundle all necessary (.js) files and push them to the server together with package.json, so I can still run `npm install`? **What would be a better way**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that you don't want to be compiling typescript on a production server. Generally, you want to take care of all building and dependency management before you hit production. This means creating a build pipeline that outputs a standalone application for deployment.

A typical build pipeline might look like this:

`npm install` → `lint` → `build` → `bundle *.js and node_modules` → `deploy`

A setup like this isolates installing dependencies, linting, and building to the pipeline. Only `*.js` files, an already installed `node_modules` directory, and `package.json` (if it contains the startup script) actually get deployed.

The build pipeline can be done manually, by running a build script and copying the output to the production server. However, a better way is to use one of the many build automation solutions that are available, such as Jenkins, Travis CI, or GitLab CI.

Comment: Hmm, this sounds like it is the very obvious way, but aren't there node_modules that *have* to be built on the target system, e.g. because they depend on native code or some environment setup? I thought that is the whole point why there are so many tutorials out there where the deploy pipeline just checks out git and runs `npm install`...

Comment: RIght. If you are compiling native code (node-gyp comes to mind), you want to make sure it is compatible between your build environment and your production environment. Ensuring compatibility can be tricky, depending on what environment dependencies your code has. For the example of node-gyp, the OS and architecture must be the same. Containerization can help manage environmental dependencies if they are complex. You still want to have a separate build and production environment. You don't want to be compiling in production.

Comment: OK. So I understand you'd create an identical build environment (e.g. with help of containers) to ensure copying node_modules doesn't break anything. Just for completeness: how far does the being identical part have to be? are there modules that depend on installed programs, e.g. can the mongoose module be installed correctly in an environment where no mongoDB is present and then moved to production where mongoDB is installed?

Comment: Usually you only have to worry about environment compatibility when you have modules that have to be compiled (node-gyp). Mongoose library can absolutely be installed without mongoDB present in the build environment. Depending on what your dependencies are, you may be able to get away with not using containers, although they have other uses besides standardizing environments.